# Azure Document DB - Java 1.9.5 | Authorization Error

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection with some documents in it. And in my application I am creating this collection first and then inserting documents. Also, based on the requirement I need to truncate (delete all documents) the collection as well. Using document db java api I have written the following code for my this purpose-

```
DocumentClient documentClient = getConnection(masterkey, server, portNo);
List<Database> databaseList = documentClient.queryDatabases("SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id='" + schemaName + "'", null).getQueryIterable().toList();
DocumentCollection collection = null;

Database databaseCache = (Database)databaseList.get(0);

List<DocumentCollection> collectionList = documentClient.queryCollections(databaseCache.getSelfLink(), "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id='" + collectionName + "'", null).getQueryIterable().toList();

// truncate logic
if (collectionList.size() > 0) {
    collection = ((DocumentCollection) collectionList.get(0));

    if (truncate) {
        try {
            documentClient.deleteDocument(collection.getSelfLink(), null);
        } catch (DocumentClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

} else { // create logic
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.setOfferType("S1");

    collection = new DocumentCollection();
    collection.setId(collectionName);
    try {
        collection = documentClient.createCollection(databaseCache.getSelfLink(), collection, requestOptions).getResource();
    } catch (DocumentClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With the above code I am able to create a new collection successfully. Also, I am able to insert documents as well in this collection. But while truncating the collection I am getting below error-

```
com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'delete
colls
eyckqjnw0ae=
```

I am using Azure Document DB Java API version 1.9.5.
It will be of great help if you can point out the error in my code or if there is any other better way of truncating collection. I would really appreciate any kind of help here.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description & code, I think the issue was caused by the code below.

```
try {
    documentClient.deleteDocument(collection.getSelfLink(), null);
} catch (DocumentClientException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It seems that you want to delete a document via the code above, but pass the argument `documentLink` with a collection link.

So if your real intention is to delete a collection, please using the method `DocumentClient.deleteCollection(collectionLink, options)`.